# Angular testing: mock the value of a constant

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine

I have a simple app:

- AppComponent gets a list of activities to display from a service
- ActivitiesService gets the list from an imported **constant**
- in my test file *activities.service.spec.ts* I would like to **mock that constant**

For convenience I've set up a StackBlitz (including the test) in 'given/when/then' form ([link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zacpdp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Factivities.services.spec.ts)) and another one with the classic 'beforeEach/it()' form ([link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yruyrz?file=src/app/services/activities.services.spec.ts)). They should be doing the same thing but some people like one style better than the other... I'd be happy if any of the two was running.

In the test I'm adding `{ provide: ACTIVITIES, useValue: fakeActivities }`, since I believe the solution has to lay there somewhere... but how do I apply it? Apparently I cannot inject it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `spyOn` on `getActivities()` method like below:

```
import { TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { ACTIVITIES } from "../data/activities-mock";
import { Activity } from "../models/activity";
import { ActivitiesService } from "./activities.service";
import Spy = jasmine.Spy;
fdescribe("ActivitiesService", () => {
  let serviceUnderTest: ActivitiesService;
  let actualResult: Activity[];

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ActivitiesService
      ]
    });
    serviceUnderTest = TestBed.inject(ActivitiesService);
  });

  it("should get Activities", () => {
    spyOn(serviceUnderTest, 'getActivities').and.returnValue(fakeActivities);
    actualResult = serviceUnderTest.getActivities();
    expect(actualResult).toEqual(fakeActivities);
  });
});

const fakeActivities: Activity[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "stretching"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "climbing"
  }
];
```

Comment: Hi OLO, thank you, but I think this is mocking the function under test itself. In the meantime I got the solution through another channel, I'll post it here later today. Thanks again though!

Comment: actually, on second thought, this is a valid solution. I'll accept it. thanks.